# Select option contains not working when validating the model MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I'm trying to select an item in my dropdownlist using jquery but it is going to empty my ActionResult, thus causing the following error: "The Payment Method field is required." Placed an alert to see if it was getting the id of the dropdownlist and it's coming right the problem is how do I send that id to my controller?

JQUERY:

```
    $("#ddlFormaPagamento").find("option:contains('Cartão de Crédito')").each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == 'Cartão de Crédito') {
                $(this).prop("selected", "selected");
            }
        });
```

My Field:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.intFormaPagamentoId, ViewBag.FormaPagamentoList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "",
        new { @Id = "ddlFormaPagamento", @style = "width:404px;" })
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your issue? what do you mean by `how do I send that id to my controller?`

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
$(this).prop({"selected": true});
```

Because `selected` is a property aka a state of being for the element it accepts a boolean value so either 1/0 or true/false or on/off in layman's terms

Also there is no need to perform an `each()` iteration because your jQuery can be simplified like this:

```
$('#ddlFormaPagamento').find('option[value="Cartão de Crédito"]').prop({"selected": true});
```

Comment: did not work =( My controller is as "0" instead of the id of the selected item

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML? `<select><option>first</option><option>second</option></select>`

Comment: <select id="ddlFormaPagamento" class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Forma de Pagamento: must be a number." name="intFormaPagamentoId" style="width:404px;" disabled="disabled"><option value=""></option>
<option value="11">Cartão de Crédito</option>
<option value="12">Dinheiro</option>
</select>

Comment: I think `disabled="disabled"` might be causing issues.

Comment: It really is because of the disabled, but as I do because I need to disable this field?

Comment: I might be completely wrong for saying disabled="disabled" is the issue. Why are you sending an ID to your controller? Your controller should be listening for a `name` such as `intFormaPagamentoId` and not `ddlFormaPagamento`

Comment: I tested here the disabled does not make a post so do not send anything